# jVector - Italian regions

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, jvectormap

I'm trying to use the Italy's map in jVector, but i can't assign a value to a specific region or an array of regions. 
I've tried and tried... but nothing.
The map is displayed but i can't assign, for example

```
"Veneto": 100,
"Lazio": 200,
"Sicilia": 350,
"Sardegna": 400....
```

I've tried also:

```
"IT-Veneto": 100,
"IT-Lazio": 200,
"IT-Sicilia": 350,
"IT-Sardegna": 400....
```

or

```
"VENETO": 100,
"LAZIO": 200,
"SICILIA": 350,
"SARDEGNA": 400....
```

and other possible combinations.

can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, in the download section of jvectorsmap I've found only the Italy's province map and no regions. Where do you get that one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jVectorMap follows iso-3166 standard. To set values for italian regions you need to use codes described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2%3aIT).